# jquery text reveal with prompt text change

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm creating a FAQ page where questions are listed but the explanations are hidden - click on the question to show the explanations.  Pretty straight forward stuff.

I want to add a little text prompt (in a `<span>`) next to the question that says "more" when the explanation is hidden, and "less" when the explanation is display.  Can't figure out how to do this.

Tried using some If/else statements, but couldn't get them working.  Is there an easier way to do this?

Here's my current script, sans the "more/less" text change:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.faqtitle').click(function () {
    $(this).next('p').animate({
            height: "toggle",
            opacity: "toggle"
        }, 400);
  });
});
```

... and here's the fiddle displaying generally what I'm working with:
http://jsfiddle.net/V5LDQ/

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.faqtitle').click(function () {
    $(this).next('p').animate({
            height: "toggle",
            opacity: "toggle"
        }, 400);
      var expand = $(this).find('span');
      if (expand.html() == "more") {
          expand.html("less");
      } else {
          expand.html("more");
      }
  });
});
```

Working fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/R3Tdq/).

---

### Edit:

Here is a nice simple way to incorporate some css fade for that text change. This is using the jQuery `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` methods. Additional documentation can be found [here](http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/fading/).

```
  var expand = $(this).find('span');
  expand.fadeOut(500, function() {
      if (expand.html() == "more") {
          expand.html("less");
      } else {
          expand.html("more");
      }
      expand.fadeIn(500);
  });
```

Working fiddle with transitions [here](http://jsfiddle.net/RhF9z/1/).

Comment: This works.  Is there any way to stylize the text change though?  Hoping to use a slide fadein/out to make the transition softer.  Also wouldn't mind delaying the change a bit

Answer (score 1):

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/yayezoro/1/edit)**

```
  $('.faqtitle').click(function(){
    var io = this.io^=1;    // Toggler stored directly into the this object
    $(this)
       .next('p').animate({height: "toggle",opacity: "toggle"}, 400)
       .end().find('span').text( io?"less":"more" );
  });
```

`.end()` method will return the selector to you clicked element, than will find the children 'span' and using a *Conditional Operator (?:)* will set the text depending on the boolean value we set using the `^=1` (`^`AKA Bitwise XOR Operator) on the `var io`. The boolean value of the clicked button is stored pretty ugly directly inside a property `io` of the `this` (element) Object (`this.io`). So it can be retrieved later.

So to explain the `.text( io?"less":"more" );`
`io` stores 1/0 respectively, knowing that `1` inside a Condition (here we use the `?:`) will evaluate in Boolean `true` we say:

`condition ? "use this if true" : "use that if false"`.

Comment: Good stuff.  Is there any way to stylize the text change transition?  Hoping to fade it in/out or at least give it a slight delay.  Simply adding a .delay() to the function didn't seem to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily with `.toggle()`

```
$('.faqtitle').click(function () {
  $(this).next('p').toggle();
});
```

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YW74Y/) demonstrating.

Comment: The poster wanted the "more" to change to "less". The comment on the question answers that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Ternary operators are fun.

```
      $('.faqtitle span').text() == 'more' ? $('.faqtitle span').text('less') : $('.faqtitle span').text('more');
```